# Deserialize Json into a C# Object

Tags: c#, json

I am aware this topic has been previously posted. But I tried following them. However, my result is still not being shown. I would appreciate any help possible. Thanks in advance. :) I am getting the following error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I am trying to deserialize a JSON object into a c# object to output the property score.

My Json output from json = toneAnalyzer.Tone(toneInput) :

```
{
  "document_tone" : {
    "tones" :
      [
        {
          "score" : 0.70123,
          "tone_id" : "tentative",
          "tone_name" : "Tentative"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I have carried out the following code:

```
    var json = toneAnalyzer.Tone(toneInput); // this is my json source

    DocTone myResult = new DocTone();
    myResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocTone>(json.Response);

    foreach (var myTone in myResult.tones)
    {
        Console.Write(myTone.Score);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    //  Console.WriteLine(myResult);
    //  Console.WriteLine(result.Response);

}

public class MyTone1
{ 
    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public double Score { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tone_id")]
    public string Tone_Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tone_name")]
    public string Tone_Name { get; set; }
}

public class DocTone
{
    [JsonProperty("tones")]
    public List<MyTone1> tones { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it's at the bottom of the code. Sorry I have never used this before. So not familiar with the format.

Comment: You're deserializing a list so should be JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocTone>>(json.Response);

Comment: @auburg no, that's not correct. only `tones` **within** the JSON is a list. The outer structure is an object. I suspect the real issue is that the C# structure doesn't account for the `"document_tone"` property.

Comment: Does var json even have a "Response" property?

Comment: yes it does a have response property and it is returning the correct data. It is just the deserialize that is not working.

Comment: I really dislike how a lot of SO questions are getting closed with "This question already has answers here" and a pretty much completely unrelated or outdated answer. :(
The question has been correctly answered below and the answer has nothing to do with the linked question "What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?".

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  It is not a duplicate of the referenced answer - the problem is caused by incorrect JSON deserialisation!  It should be reopened.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UcnNty - working demo of a correct structure to deserialise it. I recommend using a tool such as http://json2csharp.com/ to generate matching C# classes based on any given JSON sample.

Comment: @ADyson. Thank you man. Thats cool. i did not knwo there was a tool that does it for you. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a slight mistake with the object you are deserialising to.

Your root object is not `DocTone`, but actually the object that has a property containing the `DocTone` object (via the `document_tone` element).

Define a root object (call it whatever you like) and then deserialise to that:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("document_tone")]
    public DocTone DocTone { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialise and then access via the `DocTone` property:

```
RootObject myResult;
myResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.Response);

foreach (var myTone in myResult.DocTone.tones)
    ...
```

The reason that you are experiencing the `NullReferencException` is because when you deserialise to a `DocTone` object, the `tones` property is `NULL`.

Comment: either that or, if possible, change the json to not include the `"document_tone" : {` and corresponding closing `}`

Comment: @Longoon12000 You are right that you could do that, but I fail to see why hacking the JSON would be better than correctly deserialising it.